# how do i apply magentic effect to all sides (left , right , bottom) it only applies it to the top currently

Tags: javascript, html

guys how do i apply the magnetic effect to all sides left,bottom,right. right now it only applies it top part

her the vid of it https://youtu.be/M1F6CR2cs44

i want it to be like this without the color change and also  i didnt use the code of this video as its not fitting into my code i used the magentic effect code from another website.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8befSxPPKpY

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".navv");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    const position = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.pageX - position.left - position.width / 2;
    const y = e.pageY - position.top - position.height / 2;

    btn.children[0].style.transform = "translate(" + x * 0.3 + "px, " + y * 0.5 + "px)";
  });
});

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){
    btn.children[0].style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/metropolis" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="firstnav">
        <a href=""><img src="imgs/logo.png" alt="" class="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>—
            <li><a href="">Community</a></li>—
            <li><a href="">Catalogue</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navv">
        <div class="navm" g-component="SampleComponent">
            <img src="imgs/menu.png" alt="" id="fanav" onclick="nav()">
        </div>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="cart">Cart 0</a>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The crucial part is that you didn't include your css. The properties of the element (the size of each navv in your example) will determine at which point the mouseover event will be triggered.

To simplify the issue I've added a more minimal example. I have an anchor which contains a span. as you can see as soon as you enter the blue area, the event will be triggered (since you put the event listener on the anchor) and the span will move. If you can't make it work with this example, please include your css.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
btns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
        const position = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.pageX - position.left - position.width / 2;
        const y = e.pageY - position.top - position.height / 2;

        btn.children[0].style.transform = "translate(" + x * 0.3 + "px, " + y * 0.5 + "px)";
      });
    });

    btns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){
        btn.children[0].style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
      });
    });
```

```css
.btn{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn span{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: transform 0.15s linear;
}

a {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
    <span>Hover Me</span>
</a>
```